# Disable direct access to php page but allow the access if reached from specific page

Tags: php, permissions

I have a form wich collect data and send it to process_form.php this file does various funcions but needs user input data in order to work, if executed without user data can create some problems. 
I dont want someone can type www.mysite.com/process_form.php but i want allow his access only if the referring url is www.mysite.com/compile.php 
Possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, by using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], **however** be warned to use this variable, as it can be manipulated and is unreliable. From php.net:

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

I suggest you edit your process_form.php to check if the inputted data needed for the function, is present. If you have a form with GET you can use:

```
if(!empty($_GET['myFormFieldName'])) { 
    // process
}
```

or if using POST:

```
if(!empty($_POST['myFormFieldName'])) {
    // process
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should sessions to validate if the user has gone through the right process to reach the last page.